# JavaFx on Linux 2.4.26/ARM9 Processor/200MHz/32MB RAM

Tags: java, linux, javafx

I am new to JavaFx technology, I would like to know whether I can have JavaFx on a Linux kernel 2.4.26 (no other commercial distribution), it is a touch screen based navigation system runs on a ARM9 processor (200MHz, 32MB RAM).

While searching, I found that JavaFx is supported on Linux platforms, but I couldn't find any reference to my particular version of Linux (Linux kernel 2.4.26). Is it possible to install and run JavaFx on this machine? Also please tell me whether standard JavaFx or JavaFx mobile is more suitable for this system.

regards

Jamsheer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know almost nothing about JavaFx, but to run JavaFx, you need to install Java SE first, isn't it?

This embedded java SE download page has ARM Linux Early Access binaries

http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/embedded.jsp

and [this release notes](http://java.sun.com/javase/embedded/reference/release6/EmbeddedReleaseNotes_6.html#javafx) says, its still underdevelopment and but its said you still can run simple applications with some limitations.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I will check the link.
Is it possible to run Java ME and JavaFX on ARM Linux?

Answer (score 2):

JavaFX is not supported on ARM at this time.

Answer (score 0):

From:

http://java.sun.com/javase/embedded/reference/release6/EmbeddedReleaseNotes_6.html#javafx

How to Run JavaFX Applications

JavaFX™ support in Java SE for Embedded (headful version) on Linux ARM is still under development at the time of this writing.

However, you can run simple JavaFX applications on Java SE for Embedded 6 Update 10 on Linux ARM v6, although with some limitations. JavaFX applications cannot be run from a web browser on the Linux ARM platform. You must manually download the JavaFX 1.2 Software Development Kit (SDK), compile the sample applications included, and run the applications from a shell. These steps are explained in detail below.